# Symfony2: Update @Assert\File value

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

I have an existing entity in a symfony2 framework.

Originally, the maxSize was set to 6000000.

```
/**
* @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
*/
```

I have updated it to 20000000 to handle larger attachments.

```
/**
* @Assert\File(maxSize="20000000")
*/
```

I have made this change on my local machine and tested successfully with app_dev.php, but if I try to upload a file larger than the old value, without using app_dev.php, I am thrown a validation error, as it's still using the old entity maxSize.

How do I update this?

app/console cache:clear doesn't seem to update the entity values.

Comment: did you try `app/console cache:clear --evn=prod`?

Comment: also check the value of the `upload_max_filesize` in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: the php.ini would not allow the file upload, whether in app_dev or not correct?

Comment: app/console cache:clear --env=prod did not work either

Comment: Yes the `upload_max_filesize` is a PHP parameter. Where as the `File` assertion is only valid at application level.

Comment: In sf1, you would call build-model to update the model. This does not exist in sf2, so there must be a command which updates the model with all of the new annotation settings correct?

Comment: The `doctrine:schema:update` Command does this for database properties. But the `Assert`ions are not on database level so they are not affected. What are your settings for `upload_max_filesize` in your `php.ini`? Make sure to also check the `cli/php.ini`.

Comment: upload_max_filesize = 50M which should allow for the 20Mb upload.